# How to target animation inside specific child container in wpf?

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

Here my problem is ,My animation starts from right to left. But it is rendering over the combo box even i set animation transform inside dockpanel where I wanted to show animation within it. Not over combo.Margin of animation should be next from combo.what is going wrong.Please help me with this.
This is my code  :
[Animation is rendered over combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iET10.png)

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbExchange" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left" SelectionChanged="cmbExchange_SelectionChanged"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ExchangeList, Source=TickerViewModel}" 
              SelectedIndex="1" SelectedItem="{Binding selectedExchange}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="75" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="Auto" Name="BaseTickerPane" Loaded="BaseTickerPane_Loaded">
        <StackPanel.Visibility>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource visibilityConv}" Path="isVisible" Mode="TwoWay"/>
        </StackPanel.Visibility>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="TickerItems" Height="20" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FeedItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackOfTickerItem" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=StockName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White"  Name="lblStockName"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageURI,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="image"  Height="20"  Width="Auto"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Change,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="White"  Name="lblchange"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transfer" X="75" />
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
            <ItemsControl.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="tickerAnimation3">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation From="1200" To="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter},ElementName=BaseTickerPane}" Duration="00:1:00"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                             Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=TickerItems}"
                  Storyboard.TargetName="TickerItems"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="tickerAnimation3"></PauseStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                    <ResumeStoryboard  BeginStoryboardName="tickerAnimation3"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ItemsControl.Triggers>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Be aware that a RenderTransform does not affect layout and is not affected by layout. The element first gets its layout done and is transformed afterwards. It may then of course cover other elements outside its parent containers.

Comment: I dont want to cover animation over combobox. it should starts from next to combo.i have attached screen shot as well. Should i change animation to and from ?  or how to set margin of the animation to start from ?